# Loop in a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my Sql database, I have tables

1 Account_Customer 
-AccountID
-CustomerID
-Account_CustomerID

2 Accounts 
-AccountID
-Balance

3 Customers
-CustomerID
-Name
-Sex
-Age

4 Loans
-LoanID
-Amount
-BranchName

5 Loan_Customer
-Loan_CustomerID
-LoanID
-CustomerID

and I want to write a stored procedure for 
Listing customers together with their number of accounts, total account balances, number of loans, and total loan amounts, living in a given city, having given sex and age, and having accounts and/or loans in a given branch.

I can do the number of accounts and total account balances in my program but I need a stored procedure for my assignment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want all that in one query? Or several separate queries?

Comment: I think you're missing a field in the Accounts table for what you want to do. You said you want to filter where customers have an account in a certain branch, but there is no branch information associated with the account... or if there is, I can't see it...

Comment: There is nothing in the provided tables that tells us what city a customer lives in

Comment: Ok, I just didnt copy all information, 
I need 3 different stored procedures 
1.for a given city
2.given sex and age
3.given accounts or loans in a branch

but one example of a query loop would help me enought !

Comment: i believe this can be done with a single query, joining all tables together

Comment: @Dapeng I can do that but I need to have a loop for #number of loans and total loan amount.

Comment: @Kubi: No, you really don't. Ever heard of the COUNT and SUM functions?

Comment: well no ! :) I am expecting that from this thread

Comment: @Rory can you give me a little example for COUNT and SUM? It is going to be enough for me !

Comment: @Kubi: Check the answers below for examples of their usage. SQL can do a lot without loops, its one of the things that makes it so powerful. Normally when you think you need a loop, there is a simpler and quicker way to do it. When in doubt, the F1 key is your friend ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, lets give this a bash (although I still think we're missing a few pieces)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectCustomerDetailsBySex
  @Sex <your data type here>
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT cus.CustomerID,
    cus.Name,
    COUNT(acc.AccountID) AS AccountCount,
    SUM(acc.Balance) AS AccountBalance,
    COUNT(loa.LoanID) AS LoanCount,
    SUM(loa.Amount) AS LoanTotal
  FROM Customers cus
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Account_Customer ac ON cus.CustomerID = ac.CustomerID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounts acc ON ac.AccountID = acc.AccountID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Loan_Customer lc ON cus.CustomerID = lc.CustomerID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Loans loa ON lc.LoanID = loa.LoanID
  WHERE cus.Sex = @Sex
  GROUP BY cus.CustomerID,
    cus.Name;
END
```

Will that do as an example, or would you like me to do another?

Comment: not necessary. thank you! 

but I get an error : 
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Customers.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: No problem! Now I'm going to bed, it's almost 4am here. Everybody have a safe and fun New Years!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989340/join-query-returns-me-wrong

I am still having a problem with the same assignment, can you help me ?